# Why does my switch case work here, but if does not?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, switch-statement

I am learning how to use Lists, and in my following example the switch case works but (what I deem as) the equivalent if statement does not. Can you tell me why?

```
public class Kapitel14 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<String>();
    testList.add("Cousin");
    testList.add("Doof");
    testList.add("Dorf");
    testList.add("Dortmund");
    testList.add("Franz");
    System.out.println(listCount(testList));
}

public static int listCount(ArrayList<String> newList) {

    int capDCounter = 0;
    for (String element : newList) {
        String firstLetter = Character.toString(element.charAt(0));
        switch (firstLetter) {
            case ("D"):
                capDCounter++;
                break;

            default:
                continue;
        }

        //if I use this instead it returns wrong results:
        //if (firstLetter == "D") 
        //  capDCounter++;
    }
    return capDCounter;
}
```

Comment: You can just replace "D" by 'D'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (firstLetter.equals("D"))
             capDCounter++;
```

instead of

```
if (firstLetter == "D") 
          capDCounter++;
```

`.equals()` method should be used here as you want to compare the values of strings.

Comment: Thank you! Is it because my version would have compared the adress of firstLetter to "D"?

Comment: Apparently yes. But I would term them as references instead of address.     BTW thats close analogy to C/C++.